# Custom init without arguments

Tags: ios, swift, init

I have init with optional arguments

```
init(cellClass: UICollectionViewCell.Type? = nil, contentHeight: Int? = nil) {
    self.init()

    self.setupCollectionView()

    if cellClass != nil && contentHeight != nil {
        self.hasContentCollectionView = true
        self.contentHeight = contentHeight!
        self.contentCollectionViewCellClass = cellClass!
        self.setupContentCollectionView()
    }

    self.setupConstraints()
}
```

The problem is that when I execute `init()` without params my init above is not being called. But i need it in order to setup the view.

I know there is workaround by adding non optional argument, this will help execute overtime needed init, but I don't like this solution because I don't have arguments that I can use evertime that will make sense.

How can I call this init above without arguments ?

Comment: please show more code (class and other initializers if any). Because if we assume that it is the only initializer `convenience` missing for `UICollectionViewCell` subclass

Comment: Swift init() are special methods that are called when an object is instantiated.You have created parameterized init() .parameterized init() with example. ... The reason is: When we do not declare any init() in a class, the compiler creates default one for that class, but if we declare a init() regardless of what it is default or parameterized, the compiler does not declare the default init() itself.